# Is there a way to increment a property value of a Maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, xml, maven, apache-zookeeper

I'm creating this gRPC project where I have to launch a server and register it on Zookeeper. 
I should be able to launch multiple instances of the server, but every new instance needs to have a new port or else will conflict with the servers that are already registered.

I have this maven pom.xml file where I have a property value `<ins.i>`, that should be incremented by 1 for every instance that is running. This property turns to be the last digit of `<server.port>`. If i could increment this value by 1 it would solve my problem.

I've searched by similar questions and I couldn't find any similar.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>

  <!-- Please replace 'CXX' below with your C (campus) with A (Alameda) / 
        T (Tagus); and your group number with two digits. Then delete this comment. -->
    <groupId>pt.sayf.CXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>SAYF</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>sentry-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

  <properties>


    <mainclass>pt.sayf.sentry.server.SentryServer</mainclass>

    <!-- instance number -->
    <ins.i>1</ins.i>

    <!--  name and coordinates -->
    <sentry_loc.name>IST_Taguspark</sentry_loc.name>
    <sentry.xcoord>38.737613</sentry.xcoord>
    <sentry.ycoord>-9.303164</sentry.ycoord>

    <server.host>localhost</server.host>
    <server.port>809${ins.i}</server.port>
    <sentry.path>/grpc/sayf/${sentry.name}/${ins.i}</sentry.path>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- contract brings gRPC dependencies with it -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-contract</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>depot-contract</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-resources-plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.exec-maven-plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- to prevent deprecation warning: -->
                <killAfter>-1</killAfter>
                <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>${zookeeper.url}</argument>
                    <argument>${server.host}</argument>
                    <argument>${server.port}</argument>
                    <argument>${sentry.path}</argument>
                    <argument>${sentry_loc.name}</argument>
                    <argument>${sentry.xcoord}</argument>
                    <argument>${sentry.ycoord}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.appassembler-maven-plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                        <id>${project.artifactId}</id>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the property every time you run something like `clean install`?

Comment: @JFMeier Yes I would like to change it every time I run `compile exec:java`

Comment: Scaling should be done outside this scope, at the virtual network layer.  If you're using maven to spin up images, something is very wrong.  What type of container orchestration package are you using?  Docker compose, docker swarm, Kubernetes, RedHat OpenShift?